# Remove reference to another object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var b = {};
var a = b;
b.test = 123;
console.log(a.test);
```

I am trying to write code similar to the above, however for sake of not having to describe context I'll display that instead ^

After the line `a = b` I want to lose the reference from a to b, so I can update b without it affecting a, and vice-versa

Is this possible?

Comment: its better you perfrom copy operation..i.e. copy object rather than assigning reference...this is for cloning object please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: You have to make copy of variable. How to clone object you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can clone your object with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var a = Object.assign({}, b);
```

Comment: But be aware that this is an ES6 feature and currently not available in all browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer).

Comment: @LUH3417 Yes that would be necessary.

Comment: It may not work as expected for deep objects.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `JSON.stringify(obj)` and then `JSON.parse` to the string.
So it'll be something like that:

```
let obj= {
    hello: 'hello'
};
let string = JSON.stringify(obj);
let newObj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Or a shorter, one-line way:

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: Wouldn't retain functions.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Object.assign()`, `Object.create()` or spread operator will **not** help you with **arrays** in objects *(works with non-array properties though)*.

```
let template = {
    array: []
};
let copy = { ...template };
console.log(template.array); // As expected, results in: []
copy.array.push(123);
console.log(template.array); // Output: [123]
```

But this **can** be solved using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, as **already said**.

```
let template = {
    array: []
};
let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(template));
console.log(template.array); // Output: []
copy.array.push(123);
console.log(template.array); // Output: []
```

Wonder if it is the most adequate solution...
Excuses if I'm missing something, am only a beginner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the array part explanation

Comment: works fantastic for array. life saving...